# SQL Server Time Data Type Error

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table with two time columns.  I'm trying to compare these times and generate a specific output if they match.

So far I am unable to perform an equality comparison on these values, they all result in the following error:

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Here is an example of my table and the different ways I've attempted to perform an equality comparison.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Time_Table](
[RowID] [int] NOT NULL,
[OpenTime] [time](7) NOT NULL,
[CloseTime] [time](7) NOT NULL)
GO

insert into Time_Table values (1,'01:00:00', '01:00:00')

CASE WHEN OpenTime = CloseTime THEN 'MATCH' ELSE OpenTime END
CASE WHEN CAST(OpenTime AS DATETIME) = CAST(CloseTime AS DATETIME) THEN 'MATCH' ELSE OpenTime END
CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE,CAST(OpenTime AS DATETIME),CAST(CloseTime AS DATETIME)) = 0 THEN 'MATCH' ELSE OpenTime END
```

All of these statements result in the error I pasted above.  Does SQL Server inherently store this data type as character data?  As you can see in my DDL I am using the 'Time' Data type and not a character data type.

I'm wondering if this is due to the collation setting on this server?  (Latin1_General_BIN)

Any help or suggestions on performing a time comparison / equality check with the 'Time' Data type would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How do you suppose that you can store `'MATCH'` as a time data type?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  I got caught up in the minutiae and failed to see my obvious blunder there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to cast time value into varchar first. 
Use `Cast(OpenTime as varchar(8))` in all of your case statement

```
CASE WHEN OpenTime = CloseTime THEN 'MATCH' ELSE Cast(OpenTime as varchar(8)) END
```

The reason is that in a case construct,

```
select case Conditional expression THEN whatever this else that end
```

`this` and `that` have to be the same `datatype`.